# App crashes after custom cell is created 250 times

Tags: iphone, ios

I use a custom cell in my app. When a user taps a table row, a custom cell appears:

```
#import "SonaraamatuKontroller.h"
#import "TolkegaLahter.h"

//Lahtris kasutatava teksti fondi suurus 
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
//Tabelilahtri laius
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
//Tabeli sisu äärise kaugus lahtri servadest
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 5.0f

@implementation SonaraamatuKontroller 
@synthesize sonaraamatuSisukord=sonaraamatuSisukord;
@synthesize sonaraamatuTabel;
@synthesize valitudLahtriIndexPath;
@synthesize tolkegaLahter;
@synthesize audioPleier;
@synthesize sonaraamatuFailinimi;
@synthesize sonaraamatuNavribaNimi;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;

NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sonaraamatuFailinimi ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];

NSArray *sisukordData = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                   format:&format
                                                         errorDescription:&error];


if (sisukordData)   {
    self.sonaraamatuSisukord = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sonaraamatuSisukord count]];
    for (NSDictionary *sisukordDictionary in sisukordData) {
        [self.sonaraamatuSisukord addObject:sisukordDictionary];
    }
} 

self.navigationItem.title=sonaraamatuNavribaNimi;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
//Teise vaatesse liikumisel pannakse audiopleier seisma
[audioPleier stop];
// Release anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {   
    //Loeme tabeli sektsioonide arvu - kuna praegusel juhul on sisukorras ainult üks liige (sõnaraamat "Item 0"), siis on ka sektsioone üks
    return [sonaraamatuSisukord count];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Loeme vastavas sektsioonis asuvate ridade arvu
    NSMutableArray *sisukordItems = [[sonaraamatuSisukord objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Items"];
    return [sisukordItems count];       
}


- (CGFloat) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
if(valitudLahtriIndexPath != nil
   && [valitudLahtriIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] )
    return 95; 


    NSMutableArray *sisukordItems = [[sonaraamatuSisukord objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Items"];

    NSDictionary *sisukordItem = [sisukordItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *text = [sisukordItem objectForKey:@"Valjend"];    

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);


    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 25.0f);
    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if((valitudLahtriIndexPath != nil)
   && [valitudLahtriIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] 
   ) 

{   //NSLog (@"ValitudPath: %@", valitudLahtriIndexPath);
    static NSString *TolkegaLahtriTunnus = @"TolkegaLahter";

    TolkegaLahter *cell = (TolkegaLahter *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TolkegaLahtriTunnus];

    if (cell == nil) {      
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TolkegaLahter" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tolkegaLahter;   


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    //Lisame gradiendi:
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradient setCornerRadius:9.0f];
    //[gradient setMasksToBounds:YES];
    //[gradient setBorderWidth:0.8f];
    //[gradient setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.122 green:0.2 blue:1 alpha:0.95] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.041 green:0.1 blue:0.33 alpha:0.95] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.122 green:0.2 blue:1 alpha:0.95] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.48],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sisukordItems = [[sonaraamatuSisukord objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Items"];
    NSDictionary *sisukordItem = [sisukordItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.valjend.text=[sisukordItem objectForKey:@"Valjend"];
    cell.tolge.text=[sisukordItem objectForKey:@"Tolge"];


    [sonaraamatuTabel scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];

    self.tolkegaLahter = nil;

    return cell;

} 

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//Loome lahtrisse labeli
UILabel *label = nil;    

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //Esialgu on label tühi (asub punktis 0,0 ning on suurusega 0,0)
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //Määrame reavahetuse stiili
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    //Minimaalne fondi suurus on ülal defineeritud konstant
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    //Esialgu on ridade arv 0
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    //Määrame fondi. Selle suuruseks on ülal defineeritud konstant
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:1];

    //Lisame labelile piirid, et programmeerimise käigus oleks paremini näha, kuhu see lahtris paigutub
    //[[label layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label]; 

    [label release];
}

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView=[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.537 green:0.18 blue:0.122 alpha:1.0];


    //Loome andmemassiivi sisukord objektidest (tuntakse ära võtme "Items" abil) andmemassiivi sisukordItems
    NSMutableArray *sisukordItems = [[sonaraamatuSisukord objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Items"];

    //Loome andmemassiivi sisukordItems objektidest sõnaraamatud sisukordItem
    NSDictionary *sisukordItem = [sisukordItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Igas lahtris kuvatakse sellele vastavas sõnaraamatus sisalduva objekti "Valjend" väärtus
    NSString *text = [sisukordItem objectForKey:@"Valjend"];


    //Sarnaselt lahtri kõrguse arvutamisele heightForRowAtIndexPath meetodis arvutame ka labeli 
    //kõrguse (sellele ei liideta ääriste kaugusi)
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    //Hangime labeli juhul kui see on nil (ja tegu ei ole vaate esialgse initsieerimisega ehk lahter ei ole nil)
    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    //Seame labeli teksti
    [label setText:text];
    //Seame labeli piirjooned
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 25.0f))];


    label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];    


return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    


    self.valitudLahtriIndexPath = indexPath; 
    if(valitudLahtriIndexPath != nil //Kui see väärtus on tõene, 
       && [valitudLahtriIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {

        [self.sonaraamatuTabel reloadData];


        NSMutableArray *sisukordItems = [[sonaraamatuSisukord objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Items"];

        NSDictionary *sisukordItem = [sisukordItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString*heliFailinimi=[sisukordItem objectForKey:@"HeliFailinimi"];

        NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];

        NSString *taustaHeliPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:heliFailinimi ofType:@"m4a"];

        [audioPleier stop];

        NSURL *taustaHeliURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:taustaHeliPath];
        NSError *error;
        audioPleier = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:taustaHeliURL error:&error];
        [audioPleier setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions 

        [audioPleier play];            
    }

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSIndexPath*selection = [self.sonaraamatuTabel indexPathForSelectedRow];
if (selection)
    [self.sonaraamatuTabel deselectRowAtIndexPath:selection animated:YES];

[self.sonaraamatuTabel reloadData];
}



- (void)dealloc {
[valitudLahtriIndexPath release];    
[sonaraamatuSisukord release], sonaraamatuSisukord=nil; 
[audioPleier release];
[sonaraamatuFailinimi release];
[sonaraamatuNavribaNimi release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

After 250 taps the app crashes and I get the message:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'TolkegaLahter''**

What could be the reason of this behaviour? A memory leak somewhere?

**EDIT**

It was about the AVAudioPlayer, which was created again and again, but not released.
So, I replaced

```
audioPleier = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:taustaHeliURL error:&error];
```

with

```
        AVAudioPlayer*ajutineAudioPleier = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:taustaHeliURL error:&error];
        self.audioPleier=ajutineAudioPleier;
        [ajutineAudioPleier release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code in your question the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? It isn't clear from your question whereabouts this code is or when it is executed.

If it is (or, for some of these, even if it isn't) there are a couple of problems with it:

- You aren't returning the cell if the dequeue method brings you something back
- You aren't configuring the cell if the dequeue method brings you something back
- Which leads me to expect that you haven't set the reuse identifier in your custom cell subclass in interface builder
- Which means you are creating a new cell each time which could give you a crash if you have a sufficient number of cells
- The scrolling call seems odd (this would only be odd if this *was* your cellForRowAtIndexPath method)

If you are repeatedly loading from nibs you may want to check out `UINib` as well.

**EDIT**

After looking at your full code, I think the problem is your audio player, you are creating and configuring a new one every time the cell is selected and this is leaking.

You should just set up the audio player on your viewDidLoad, and just tell it to play the specific sound when you select the cell.

Comment: Yes, it's in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Unfortunately, I'm not at my Mac unfortunately, so I can't check if the reuse indentifier is set. But the scrolling call has worked as I have expected - custom cell is higher than usual cell and when the user taps it, it gets partly hidden in some cases. The scrolling call helps to make it visible.

Comment: So does the tap action tell the tableview to reload the cell at that row? Can you update the question with that detail (when you're back at your mac, obviously :))

Comment: A pasted all of my m file code here. The identifier was set in my Custom Cell's NIB and the cell should be returned and configured now (it used to be like this before too, butI  misunderstood somebody's suggestions and changed the code in a way that did'nt return the cell). Anyway, it still gives the same error.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. However, as it seems to me that AVAudioPlayer has to be initiated with specific sound, I only managed to do it in way as I've shown in my updated post above. It might not be the best solution, but it doesn't give me the crash enymore.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realise at the time you can't set the sound again. Your solution is fine, your other option is to have an array of audio players, one with each sound, but that depends how many different sounds you have!

Comment: I have 1049 different sounds, so I guess an array of audio players is not an option here :)

Comment: I'll say! Stick with what you have, then.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TolkegaLahter" owner:self options:nil];
 cell = tolkegaLahter;
```

to

```
cell = [[[TolkegaLahter alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: TolkegaLahtriTunnus] autorelease];
self.tolkegaLahter = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TolkegaLahter" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
cell = self.tolkegaLahter;
```